# Dynamic downloadURL( ) call

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

I'm building a website that has, among the others, a photo gallery feature. In the gallery page, there's a map (google) with several markers and every marker is related to a specific photo.

I've got a 'markers' table in my database:

```
markers:  
id      | name     |  address | lat   | lng | gallery_id
_______________________________________________________
1       | ..       | ....     |..     | ..  | 2   
2       | ..       | ....     |..     | ..  | 2 
3       | ..       | ....     |..     | ..  | 3
4       | ..       | ....     |..     | ..  | 3
5       | ..       | ....     |..     | ..  | 10
......................
```

All the fields are populated with geolocated data and every row represents a specific photo uploaded by the user, all but gallery_id, that holds the id of the gallery that owns the photo.

In the gallery page there's the javascript to build up the google map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      //phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php, get the data from database
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          bounds.extend(marker.position);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
  </script>
```

I provide to downloadURL the `phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php` file, with which I build the xml file holding the markers table data:

```
<?php
//Start xml file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Select rows in the markers table
$query = "
        SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE 1;
";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Everything works just fine so far and, as long there's only one gallery in the database, the map and the markers are correct.
Now comes my problem: I need a way to provide to `phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php` the gallery_id, in order to perform the right query since the old one just returns every rows of markers, no matter the gallery. I was thinking to put `phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php` code right on the top of the gallery.php page and generate the xml file directly on the page, but then what should I provide to the downloadURL function? gallery.php?. Another way I was thinking about is to put some sort of `$_GET` request in the downloadURL parameter, but I can't find a way to perform that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the gallery_id with the URL,e.g.:

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax-xmlgenerator.php?id=3", function(data) {
```

And build the sql based on the get-parameter:

```
$id=@intval($_GET['id']);
if($id<1){
  exit();
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE gallery_id='.$id;
```